# Word (or words) that mean "types of property"

Tags: nouns

I'm writing an application that lists properties, and I've noticed that there are different types (or categories) of the types of a property:

- Detached
- Semi-detached
- Terraced
- End terrace

Then there are:

- House
- Bungalow
- Flat or Apartment
- Cottage
- Barn
- Mobile or Static Caravan

I'd like to know if there is a name for each of the two types above, my initial thought is that the top list are like "attachment types" but I'd like to know if there are an official name for these list types please?

Comment: Of course the words in the first list only normally apply to _some_ of the property types in the second list: having said that I like the idea of a semi-detached caravan and a detached flat. You could always treat the words in the second list as the primary description and those in the first as a secondary description; you could then hide or display the second combo box depending on the content of the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As housing is so universal and cross-border, having an official catergorisation is difficult. As a practical example, we can see how Wikipedia have handled the task: [List of house types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_house_types)

So essentially the first list involves adjectives, while the second list involves nouns. Based on this we could call the noun list 'Dwellings' and the other 'Dwelling type'. We could replace 'dwelling' with 'housing' or 'building' in both parts.